# Problems grouping in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've gotten XSLT 2.0 grouping to work, but I'm having trouble with XSLT 1.0.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE cataleg SYSTEM "cataleg.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="cataleg.css" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cataleg.xsl" ?>

<cataleg>

    <peli ordre="X">
        <titol>X-Men</titol>
        <caratula>XMen.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
    <peli ordre="B">
        <titol>X-Men 2</titol>
        <caratula>XMen2.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
    <peli ordre="C">
        <titol>X-Men: La Decisió Final</titol>
        <caratula>XMenFD.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
    <peli ordre="A">
        <titol>X-Men Origins: Wolverine</titol>
        <caratula>XMenOW.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>



</cataleg>
```

### XSLT 2.0 (working)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>PRACTICA 1 XML</title>
          <link href="https://procomprador.com/PRACTICA/cataleg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </html>
      </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cataleg">
        <div id="main">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="peli" group-by="@ordre">
        <xsl:sort select="titol"/>
            <Inicial value="{@ordre}">
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="@ordre"></xsl:value-of></h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <div class="peli">
                        <img src="https://procomprador.com/PRACTICA/imatges/{caratula}" alt=" "/>
            </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Inicial>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </div>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

### XSLT 1.0 attempt (not working)

```
<xsl:key name="contacts-by-surname" match="cataleg/peli" use="titol" />

<xsl:key name="pelis-by-surname" match="peli" use="@peli" />
<xsl:template match="cataleg">
    <xsl:for-each select="peli[count(. | key('pelis-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="surname" />
        <xsl:value-of select="surname" />,<br />
        <xsl:for-each select="key('pelis-by-peli', peli)">
            <xsl:sort select="caratula" />
            <xsl:value-of select="caratula" /> (<xsl:value-of select="titol" />)<br />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The preferred way of grouping in XSLT 1.0 is the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: thnx but I tried it also but I don't know how it works

Comment: If you've tried it and couldn't make it work, then post your best attempt so that we can help you with it. Also, if you search here for *Muenchian* you will find over 1000 examples you can use to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT 2.0 stylesheet groups the `peli` elements by their `ordre` attribute. If you take an XML example where some `peli` have the same `ordre`:

**XML**

```
<cataleg>
    <peli ordre="X">
        <titol>X-Men</titol>
        <caratula>XMen.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
    <peli ordre="A">
        <titol>X-Men 2</titol>
        <caratula>XMen2.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
    <peli ordre="X">
        <titol>X-Men: La Decisió Final</titol>
        <caratula>XMenFD.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
    <peli ordre="A">
        <titol>X-Men Origins: Wolverine</titol>
        <caratula>XMenOW.jpg</caratula>
    </peli>
</cataleg>
```

and apply the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="pelis-by-ordre" match="peli" use="@ordre" />

<xsl:template match="/cataleg">
     <html>
        <xsl:for-each select="peli[count(. | key('pelis-by-ordre', @ordre)[1]) = 1]">
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ordre" />
            </h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('pelis-by-ordre', @ordre)">
                <div>
                    <xsl:value-of select="titol" /> 
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get:

**Result**

```
<html>
<h1>X</h1>
<div>X-Men</div>
<div>X-Men: La Decisió Final</div>
<h1>A</h1>
<div>X-Men 2</div>
<div>X-Men Origins: Wolverine</div>
</html>
```

rendered:

[image]